# What's wrong with the following method call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

I have a Model (ASP.NET MVC 4, C#) Called HoursOfOperation:

```
public class HoursOfOperation
{
    public List<DayTimes> Monday { get; set; }
    public List<DayTimes> Tuesday { get; set; }
    public List<DayTimes> Wednesday { get; set; }
    public List<DayTimes> Thursday { get; set; }
    public List<DayTimes> Friday { get; set; }
    public List<DayTimes> Saturday { get; set; }
    public List<DayTimes> Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

and a DayTimes

```
public class DayTimes
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

now I'm trying to add a new set to the Monday entity like below:

```
var _vm = new HoursOfOperation();

_vm.Monday.Add(new DayTimes{
      From = day.From.ToString(),
      To = day.To.ToString(),
      Status = (int)day.Status
});
```

as soon as the above statement is excecuted I'm getting a `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` Exception

Now I have checked and `day.From.ToString()` has a `"08:00:00"`, day.To.ToString() has `"09:30:00"` and day.Status has a `1` at the time at which this statement throws the exception.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `Monday` is not instantiated.

You should do something like

```
_vm.Monday = new List<DayTimes>();
```

or alternatively, make all instantiations in `HoursOfOperation`'s constructor like so:

```
public HoursOfOperation()
{
   Monday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Tuesday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Wednesday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Thursday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Friday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Saturday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Sunday = new List<DayTimes>()
};
```

Comment: Wow, I'm very new to C# and OOP but I actually knew that and missed it. Thank you, and Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Your lists are null at this point. So

```
_vm.Monday
```

..will throw an exception. You have to `new` them up in the constructor:

```
public HoursOfOperation() {
    Monday = new List<DayTimes>();
    // ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The various List properties are not being initialised; you need to add

```
_vm.Monday = new List<DayTime>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instances of the lists of day times:

```
var hoursOfOperation = new HoursOfOperation
{
   Monday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Tuesday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Wednesday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Thursday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Friday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Saturday = new List<DayTimes>(),
   Sunday = new List<DayTimes>()
};
```